# Using ReactiveUI V8+ RoutedViewHost in WPF

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I am trying to upgrade my application template up to V8+. Previously working xaml seems to be broken. .NET Framework 4.7.2, ReactiveUI 8.3.1

```
    <!--Client Area-->
    <reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost x:Name="ViewHost" 
                               Margin="3,9.667,3.333,3" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="stretch" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               Grid.Row="1">

        <reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost.DefaultContent>

            <WrapPanel>


            </WrapPanel>

        </reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost.DefaultContent>
    </reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost>
```

Gives a design-time warning:
"Don't know how to detect when Reactiveui.RoutedViewHost is activated/deactivated, you may need to implement IActivationFoViewFetcher". Am I missing a package or has there been a fundamental change in RoutedViewHost behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new nuget package called reactiveui.wpf that you need to include.

This will register a IActivationForViewFetcher.

Comment: Installed. I followed the package installation sequence as specified for WPF applications [here](https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/installation/setting-up-a-new-project)

Comment: To clarify my comment above... I had installed per directions, but still have the error...

Comment: Try calling:
 resolver.InitializeReactiveUI();

That extension method is what will register the View Activator, but this should happen automatically when RxUI is activated. We have a bug in waiting to be released that can cause issues on WinForms that should resolve your issue.

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/pull/1651

Comment: No joy. Project [repo](https://github.com/ApexAutomation/BaseApp) if anyone wants to take a look.

Comment: You need to add a nuget reference to System.Reactive.Compatibility for starters. This is needed if you are referencing a Rx 3.1.1 library (RxUI is still 3.1.1). I don't see any design time error?

Comment: Added package, same issue. [This is what I see](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kclw56frnge92u/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Mind logging a bug on github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui ? 

It's because in the RoutedViewHost we do a check for to see if we are in a UnitTest, but this should also return true if we are in design mode. This isn't happening.

Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know, this issue was fixed with RxUI 8.4.1 which was released this morning.